# Can Local And Session Storage Be used in html 4?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, local-storage, html4, session-storage

I have 2 columns containing data in my SQLite database. My application is written in HTML4.

Now what I need to do is, based on the data that is clicked, my application should take me to the next page with the userid of the data that is clicked so that I can proceed further.

My question is: How do I pass the userid of the item that is clicked to the next page?

I am completely new to Local and Session Storage. In fact I have never used this before. More information regarding them will make my problem a lot easier.

Comment: anyone has any opinion  regarding the above mentioned question , really need some answers....

Comment: ?? anyone out there who knows about the above mentioned question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, no.

LocalStorage is part of HTML5 standard specification and is used as an alternative to cookie/session storage. Having that said, you could use either sessions or cookies (depending on the purpose of your storage) instead while keeping in mind that these alternatives probably won't be as efficient for storing and structuring locally stored data of considerable weight as localStorage.